# How can I fill empty cells

Tags: python, pandas, nan

I wanna fill `NaN` cells

For example, if this is my DataFrame:

| name | id |
| --- | --- |
| Mike | 12 |
| Toby | 13 |
| Kevin | 14 |
| Toby |  |
| Kevin |  |
| Mike |  |

I would like to get this output:

---

| name | id |
| --- | --- |
| Mike | 12 |
| Toby | 13 |
| Kevin | 14 |
| Toby | 13 |
| Kevin | 14 |
| Mike | 12 |

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming NaNs in the empty cells (if not, first replace `''` with `pd.NA`):

```
df['id'] = df.groupby('name')['id'].transform('first')
```

Or, to simply `ffill`:

```
df['id'] = df.groupby('name')['id'].ffill()
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you don't have any NaN or other values in `id` columns which will be max (or change `max()` to acc.)

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[['A','1'], ['B','2'], ['C','3'], ['C',''], ['B',''], ['A','']], columns=["name", "id"])
sub_df = df.groupby("name").apply(lambda row: row["id"].max())
df["id"] = df.apply(lambda row: sub_df[row["name"]], axis=1)
```